# ARM - detecting whether multiply result fits in 32 bit

Tags: assembly, arm

In my assembly procedure, at one point I need to multiply two unsigned 32-bit integers, and return error if the result is too large to fit into 32-bit integer.

So I do this:

```
muls r3, r1, r2    @ r1, r2
bcs multiply_error
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as I expected - I thought that carry flag would be set if the result is too large, but when r1=1 and r2=1, the carry flag is set as well (why?). I also tried checking overflow flag - it turned out it isn't set at all (at least in tests I tried: r1=1, r2=1 and r1=UINT_MAX, r2=2).

How the flags work in this case? How to check, if r1 * r2 fits in 32-bits?

Comment: The instruction set reference specifically says "Does not affect the C or V flag.".

Comment: [Detecting Overflow from MUL](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/detecting-overflow-from-mul)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the ARM documentation for the `MUL` instruction:

> - the C flag is set to a meaningless value
> - the V flag is unchanged

so there's no help there.  Instead you need to use the `UMULL` instruction (or `SMULL` if you want signed), which multiplies two 32-bit values producing a 64-bit result in two registers, and then test the upper register the see if it is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

if the hardware doesnt help you can think about it a bit from what you already know.   the number 4 is binary 0b100 which is zero times two to the power 0 plus zero times two to the power 1 plus one times two to the power 2.  Our most significant bit is 2 to the power 2.   multiply that by 13 whose most significant bit is 2 to the power 3.   so we have 2^2 * (2^3 + 2^2 + 2^0) which distributes (2^2 * 2^3) + (2^2 * 2^2) and so on, our most significant bit comes from (2^2 * 2^3) which with another math property comes to 2^(2+3) or 2^5.  so right there we now we need at least 6 bits, there exists the possibility that the msbit of addition when we put all these things together has an carry over so that means we need 7 bits to multiply a 3 bit number (most significant non zero bit is 2 to the power 2) times a 4 bit number (msb is 2 to the power 3).  3+4 = 7 bits.  For unsigned, for signed you have to account for most significant zero or most significant one, etc etc...

or just go with the easy path any 32 bit pattern times any 32 bit pattern requires a 64 bit result to not overflow.

as far as detection for a specific instruction set just read the processor vendors documentation for that instruction.